# How to make an image draggable when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, onclick

I am not sure how but i hope there is a way so that my image is only draggable when clicked on.

I don't want my image to be draggable unless it is selected/clicked on first.

Is there a way?? Please Help.

Comment: There is a way - initialise the [draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) jQueryUI library on the image on first click

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you need to track the mousedown and mouseup events. When a user hovers over your image and then presses the mouse button down you will enter "drag mode" and stay there until the user releases i.e. triggers "mouseup".

When inside "drag mode" you can get the offsets by which to translate your image by tracking the mousemove event and grabbing clientX and clientY off the passed event object. These will tell you how much the mouse has moved.